# Microsoft Excel Macro Loop. Password Generation spreadsheet that needs to repeat

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have created a simple password generator spreadsheet that when opened prompts the user for a 5 digit number in a text input box, this number is then used in a series of formulae/commands to create a password. This password is then displayed in an output message box. The spreadsheet begins as locked, unlocks itself, prompts for the number, displays the password and then locks the sheet again. After this is finished the password generator macro cannot be used again. My current macro is below:

Private Sub Auto_Open()

```
Dim InputNo As String

ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")

Range("R1").Value = InputBox("Please input your Number")

If Range("R1") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Your password is: " & Range("R2").Value

End If
ActiveSheet.Protect ("password")
```

End Sub

What I need is for the text input box, where the number is entered, to reappear once the password has been displayed so that this file can be used multiple times without having to shut it down and reopen it. Can someone help?

Comment: You should still be able to call on the `Auto_Open` macro from the Macros menu. Can you not?  http://imgur.com/HCM50Es   
If you don't want it to display "Auto_Open" for the macro name, you need to make some changes to the placement of your code and use of subroutines and event-handlers.   Also, you mention "loop" but nowhere in your question do you really describe how you expect this to loop, and what would terminate the loop?

Comment: Why not assign the macro to a button instead of `Auto_Open`? That way the macro can be run again simply by pressing the button

Answer (score 0):

This is a super simple way about it. The issue here is I'm not sure what you're using the "generator" for, but data will be lost everytime you re-enter. This will loop however many passwords you want, and gives them an option to exit. (Also exits if password is invalid).

```
Sub Passwords()

Dim PWNum As Long
PWNum = 10 'Set to however many passwords you want to "calculate"

ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")

For i = 1 To PWNum
  Range("R1").Value = InputBox("Please input your Number, enter 0 to exit")
    If Range("R1") = 0 Or Len(Range("R1").Value) <> 5 Then 'Exits Sub if they enter 0 or not 5 digits
      MsgBox "Invalid Password."
      Exit Sub
    ElseIf Range("R1") > 0 Then
      MsgBox "Your password is: " & Range("R2").Value
    End If
Next i

ActiveSheet.Protect ("password")
End Sub
```